# How do I return results from a browser using sequeilize on nodejs express?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I checked the results of the query using console.log(). So I wanted to see this in the browser. I get an error on the console when I open the url(`http://localhost:3000/api/menu/all`) through my browser.

```
GET /api/menu/all 200 11.418 ms - -
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM Menus
[ [ TextRow {
      id: 1,
      parent_id: null,
      name: 'Admin',
      url: '/admin',
      order: 0,
      description: 'admin page category',
      is_admin: 'Y',
      is_active: 'Y',
      created_at: 2019-02-23T21:12:10.000Z,
      updated_at: 2019-02-23T21:12:10.000Z },
    TextRow {
      id: 2,
      parent_id: null,
      name: 'Index',
      url: '/',
      order: 0,
      description: 'publish page category',
      is_admin: 'N',
      is_active: 'Y',
      created_at: 2019-02-23T21:12:10.000Z,
      updated_at: 2019-02-23T21:12:10.000Z } ] ]
Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
  at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:482:11)
  at ServerResponse.header (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
  at ServerResponse.json (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:264:10)
  at ServerResponse.send (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
  at models.sequelize.query.then (/Users/master/project/demo/server/app/controllers/MenuController.js:9:9)
  at tryCatcher (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
  at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
  at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
  at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
  at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
  at _drainQueueStep (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
  at _drainQueue (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
  at Async._drainQueues (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
  at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/master/project/demo/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
  at processImmediate (timers.js:637:19)
```

I have tried many things, but I do not know how to solve `Can not set headers after they are sent to the client`.

Here are my codes

**/router/api.js**

```
const app = require('express');
const router = app.Router();

const menuController = require('../app/controllers/MenuController');

router.get('/menu/all', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(menuController.list(req, res))
});

module.exports = router;
```

**/app/controllers/MenuController.js**

```
const models = require('../models/Index');

exports.list = (req, res) => {

  const query = 'SELECT * FROM Menus';
  models.sequelize.query(query).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data);
  });

};
```

How do I fix my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `res.send()` twice in your code. Once in *api.js* and once more in *MenuController.js*.
If you let *MenuController.js* be the only one to call `res.send()`, you should be fine.

Calling `res.send` with an argument counts the length of the data being sent, creates a list of HTTP headers and sends them to the client.
Then, when you call `res.send` once more, the response has already been sent and is not possible to change any more.

I'm guessing the output your client is getting now is empty, as the call to `menuController.list` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks to you, I made a step forward. I modified `res.send (data)` to `return data`.
There is no error on the server, but the client still has no results.

Instead, `< The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.>` is being output on browser console.

Comment: finally I got result wha i want! 
router: remove `res.send` but `menuController.list(req, res)`, controller: `res.send(data);`